# laravel morphTo how to use custom columns?

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables like this

```
business:
|--id--|--owner_code--|--owner_type--|
|---1--|--WSWJDIXSWS--|---company----|
|---2--|--ADSOOEKL23--|---personal---|
company:
|--id--|-----code-----|----name---|
|---1--|--WSWJDIXSWS--|----ibm----|
|---2--|--SDFSDFSDFS--|----h3c----|
presonal:

|--id--|-----code-----|-----name----|
|---1--|--ADSOOEKL23--|-----jack----|
|---2--|--SDFSDFSDFS--|----brown----|
```

Model Company:

```
class Company extends Model
{
    public function business() {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Business', 'owner');
    }
}
```

Model Personal:

```
class Personal extends Model

    {
        public function business() {
            return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Business', 'owner');
        }
    }
```

Model Business:

```
class Business extends Model
{

    public function owner(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

IndexController:

```
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        //DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
        //$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
        $businesses = Business::get();
        $businesses->load('owner');

        return view('index')->with(compact('businesses'));

    }
}
```

view:index.blade

```
<table bgcolor="#7fffd4"  width="400">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#f5f5dc" align="center">BUSINESS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#f0f8ff">ID</td>
        <td bgcolor="#f0f8ff">OWNER_TYPE</td>
        <td bgcolor="#f0f8ff">NAME</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach($businesses as $business)
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#f0f8ff">{{$business->id}}</td>
        <td bgcolor="#f0f8ff">{{$business->owner_type}}</td>
        <td bgcolor="#f0f8ff">{{object_get($business->owner, 'name', 'unfind')}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

when i run the app all the name is "unfind"

here i use debuger
i find the queries is:

```
//select * from `businesses`
//select * from `companies` where `companies`.`id` in ('')
//select * from `personals` where `personals`.`id` in ('')

select * from `businesses`

select * from `companies` where `companies`.`id` in ('company_code_01', 'company_code_02')

select * from `personals` where `personals`.`id` in ('personal_code_01')
```

in the laravel documents, the columns is like owner_type owner_id,
here i want use the custom columns

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 5):

For convention purposes, you may want to replace `owner_code` by `owner_id` in your `business` table.

In business model you do as you did.

```
public function owner() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

In `company` and `personal` models, you add

```
public function business() {
    return $this->morphMany('App\Business', 'owner');
}
```

Then you can do

```
$busines = Business::first();
$busines->owner->name //should echo 'ibm'
```

**Update**

To define a foreign key in the morph relationship, you do

```
public function business() {
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Business', 'owner', 'business', 'owner_code');
    //Model, name, table, foreign key
}
```

The function definition of `morphToMany()` is as follows:

```
public function morphToMany($related, $name, $table = null, $foreignKey = null, $otherKey = null, $inverse = false){}
```

Comment: i have tried, the result is wrong.  the laravel use the key is id , here i want to use my custom columns

Comment: here ,my primaryKey is 'id', then final sql is <br>

select * from `companies` where `companies`.`id` in ('')<br>
select * from `personals` where `personals`.`id` in ('')<br>

Comment: I gave you the function definition from laravel, please refer to it to set your attributes in the relationship. Your last comment is not easy to comprehend.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question may not be require now but am still posting to help any newbie like me. I had the following situation in my case.

### Problem:

The catch is Laravel expects `App\Company` as the value of table:`business` column  `owner_type` table `business` *(Referring to question erd example)* where as you have `company` as value.

### Solution:

From Laravel 5.1 and higher it states, see docs by clcking [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)

> ### Custom Polymorphic Types
>
> By default, Laravel will use the fully qualified class name to store
>   the type of the related model. For instance, given the example above
>   where a `Comment` may belong to a `Post` or a `Video`, the default
>   `commentable_type` would be either `App\Post` or `App\Video`, respectively.
>   However, you may wish to decouple your database from your
>   application's internal structure. In that case, you may define a
>   relationship **"morph map"** to instruct Eloquent to use a custom name for
>   each model instead of the class name:
>
> ```
> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
>
> Relation::morphMap([
>     'posts' => 'App\Post',
>     'videos' => 'App\Video',
> ]);
> ```

You may register the `morphMap` in the boot function of your `AppServiceProvider` or create a separate service provider if you wish.

My files looked like:

```
namespace App\Models;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Like', 'entity');
    }
}

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Like', 'entity');
    }
}

class Like extends Model
{
    /*Polymorphing Model/Table*/
    public function entity()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

// In app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

/*Below line added*/
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        /*Below line added*/
        Relation::morphMap([
            'post' => 'App\Models\Post',
            'comment' => 'App\Models\Comment',
        ]);
    }
}
```

My Table `like`

```
| id | user_id | entity_id | entity_type | type |
|----|---------|-----------|-------------|------|
|    |         |           |             |      |
|    |         |           |             |      |
|    |         |           |             |      |
```