# Join 3 tables based on column values - Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

LEADS TABLE

- id
- title
- owner_id
- from_table

EMPLOYEE TABLE

- id
- first_name
- last_name
- role

ADMIN TABLE

- id
- first_name
- last_name
- role

```
$users = Leads::query();

return Datatables::make($users)

    ->editColumn('owner_id', function ($user) {
        if($user->from_table == 'employee'){
            $emp = Employee::where('id',$user->owner_id)->first();
            return $emp->first_name.' '.$emp->last_name.' ('.$emp->role.')';
        }
        if($user->from_table == 'admin'){
            $admin = Admin::where('id',$user->owner_id)->first();
            return $admin->first_name.' '.$admin->last_name.' ('.$admin->role.')';
        }
    })
```

the above solutions is working fine but we are unable to search column wise induvidual searching in datatables.

what i want is join query something like:

if(leads.from_table == employee)
// fetch data from EMPLOYEE TABLE i.e. LEADS TABLE + EMPLOYEE TABLE

- id
- title
- owner_id
- from_table
- first_name
- last_name
- role

if(leads.from_table == admin)
// fetch data from ADMIN TABLE i.e. LEADS TABLE + ADMIN TABLE

- id
- title
- owner_id
- from_table
- first_name
- last_name
- role

Comment: Unless admins are somehow not employees, I don't think I would store them in a separate table (at least not their firstnames, etc)

Comment: yes, admins are not employees, but they can assign any leads to employees.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your database structure to use polymorphic relations, they fully comply with your needs - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Answer (score 0):

from_table column should contain the class name of the parent model.

```
Add in Leads model

    public function fetchOwner()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

Add In Employee Model

```
   public function employee()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Employee', 'fetchOwner');
    }
```

Add In Admin Model

```
public function employee()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Admin', 'fetchOwner');
    }
```

```
$users = Leads::with('fetchOwner');
return Datatables::make($users)

    ->editColumn('owner_id', function ($user) {
       return $user->fetchOwner->name;
    })
```

Comment: error: Exception Message:

Trying to get property 'first_name' of non-object

Comment: dd() the $users  and verify whether 'fetchOwner' is coming or not.from_table column should contain the class name of the parent model.

Comment: showing null in fetchOwner.

BTW i have solved it by modifying my code & database.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all who tried to help..

I'm answering my own question as i found the answer after 9 days digging everywhere..

so here is the answer:

`you may want to replace owner_code by owner_id in your business table.`

so i changed the from_table to owner_type & owner_type now should contain the class name as value ex: changed admin to App\Admin & employee to App\Employee in Database

```
App\Admin.php

public function employee()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Leads', 'owner');
    }


App\Employee.php

public function employee()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Leads', 'owner');
    }

App\Leads.php

public function owner()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

Thanks to: [laravel morphTo how to use custom columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196453/laravel-morphto-how-to-use-custom-columns) (EddyTheDove) for pointing out the exact problem..